# Why can't I read session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a c# .net web application.  I create session variables but when I try to read them after I leave the page that they were created from I can't.

Created on page 1

```
Session["UserName"] = "WhatEver";
```

Then I do

```
Response.Redirect("~/whatever.aspx");
```

and try to read to read the session variable in the Page_Load method of the new page

```
string userName = Session["UserName"].ToString();
```

I receive `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Why am I receiving this error and what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: TRY THIS Response.Redirect("~/whatever.aspx",false);

Comment: Check your global.asax or other usercontrol attached on page2 or master page where did you used "Session.Abandon"

Comment: This link explains why response.redirect can cause loss of session values - http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the code containing `Session["UserName"] = "WhatEver";` is executed in page1?

Comment: @Krishna, your link is broken

Answer (score 5):

This may help:

```
Response.Redirect("~/whatever.aspx",false);
```

From [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx):

> This does not abort the thread and thus conserve the session token. Actually, this overload is used internally by RedirectFromLoginPage.

Comment: @MartyGoetz were you able to retrieve the session value on the same page before redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

Might be `sessionState` is turned off in your `config` file

```
<sessionState mode="Off/>
```

Change to `InProc` [Depends]

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout ="60" />
```

Comment: I checked the web.config and I am not setting the "seesionState" off.  I also tried adding <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout ="60" /> to the web.config.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and I managed to overcome this issue, but frankly I don't understand the solution 100%, anyways, what I done was to create a "Global.asax" file to my project from the "Add New Item" menu. Just copy-paste the following code inside your global file. The code inside this file is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ENTER_YOUR_NAMESPACE
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Code that runs on application shutdown */
            Session_End(sender, e);
        }

        void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }//end void Session_Start

        void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }//end void Session_End

    }//end class Global
}//end namespace
```

Comment: Please feel free to do any adjustments to the code above, and let me know if you figure out what it does exactly because as I said before, I don't really full understand the logic of the solution!!